# generate and encode PKCS7 message in Java

Tags: java, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I have seen many similar question asked here before, but I haven't found a proper answer yet.

I got signature which was generated and encoded by C# [SignedCms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms.aspx) .

My goal is generating the same signature in Java. I managed to create a similar signature which has the same length and most of its data. But there are not the same bits in position from 120 to 133 bits and last approximately 250 bits.

According to this [Anatomy of PKCS#7 signed message](http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/sigview/index.html). I have wrong signature and content blocks. I have tried bouncycastle but I didn't manage to generate correct signature. I'd like to use `sun.*` classes to generate and encode PKCS#7 message.

```
        X509Certificate x509 = siginingCert;
        PrivateKey priv = privateKeyFromPKCS12KeyStore;
        byte[] data = sha1HashOfDocument

        String digestAlgorithm = "MD5";
        String signingAlgorithm = "SHA1withRSA";

        AlgorithmId[] digestAlgorithmIds = new AlgorithmId[]{AlgorithmId.get(digestAlgorithm)};

        Signature sigSigner = Signature.getInstance(signingAlgorithm);
        sigSigner.initSign(priv);
        sigSigner.update(data);
        byte[] signedAttributes = sigSigner.sign();

        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(
                sun.security.pkcs.ContentInfo.DATA_OID,
                new DerValue(DerValue.tag_OctetString, data));

        X509Certificate[] certificates = {x509};

        BigInteger serial = x509.getSerialNumber();
        String issuerName = x509.getIssuerDN().getName();
        AlgorithmId dAlgId =  AlgorithmId.getAlgorithmId(digestAlgorithm);

        SignerInfo si = new SignerInfo(
                new X500Name(issuerName), serial, dAlgId, null,
                new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.RSAEncryption_oid),
                signedAttributes, null);

        SignerInfo[] signerInfos = {si};
        PKCS7 p7 = new PKCS7(digestAlgorithmIds, contentInfo, certificates, signerInfos);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        p7.encodeSignedData(bytes);
```

I got stuck on this issue and I have no idea what I missed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013111/java-implementation-of-c-sharp-signedcms is the similar to this one

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] signedData = signature.sign();

    SignerInfo si = new SignerInfo(
            new X500Name(issuerName), serial, dAlgId, null,
            new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.RSAEncryption_oid),
            signedAttributes,signedData  );
```