# How can I write a .RSA file containig the signature (with java)

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, digital-signature, file-format

My Task:

I have a Java Application that writes text files. 
These files should be signed with RSA/SHA1 by the application in order to guarantee that they are not changed during or after transport.

My first Idea was to append a "**RSA Signature Block**" at the end of the text file. But I found no information on how this block would have to be formated to be able to verify the file with a standard tool (OpenSSL?)

After searching the web for some hours I have the impression that the standard would be to write a file with an appended **.rsa extension**. (Say we have a Order123.txt we generate a file "Order123.txt.rsa") 
However I found no information on the format of these files.

The only thing I found are several links that there are .rsa files and that they can be opened with openssl, e.g:
http://file.downloadatoz.com/rsa-file-extension.html

Furthermore http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html talks about "META-INF/*.RSA" Files:

> A digital signature is a signed version of the .SF signature file.
>   These are binary files not intended to be interpreted by humans.
>
> Digital signature files have the same filenames as the .SF files but
>   different extensions. The extension varies depending on the type of
>   digital signature.
>
> .RSA (PKCS7 signature, SHA-256 + RSA)

So it seems to be a binary format...

Can somebody explain the **format of an RSA file**?
And maybe how to write this format preferably in Java?
(Assuming that the public/private key is in the keystore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files are PKCS#7 formatted signature files. Very common and virtually all S/Mime toolchains can create these. See for example

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/tooldocs/win32/javakey.html

and note that this can be used for arbitrary files.

Bouncy castle http://i-proving.com/2007/09/21/pkcs7-signatures-using-bouncy-castle/, [Java implementation of C# SignedCms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013111/java-implementation-of-c-sharp-signedcms)
and http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/javacrypto/index.html are some examples.

A more limited version which needs no extra sundry: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13910/pkcs7-encoding-in-java-without-external-libs-like-bouncycastle-etc may be of use.

Dw.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands may be useful for looking into the signature file:

```
unzip -p {file}.jar META-INF/{signer}.RSA | \
openssl pkcs7 -text -print_certs -inform DER
```

Comment: This `openssl` command only seems to output info about the signing key, not the signature itself.