# How to bypass the Certificate Expired validating when verifying the digital signature

Tags: java, .net, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I have a problem when I verify a digital signature (PKCS#7) in Java using an expired public certificate.
For more detail, it's OK in case of signing data in .NET and then **verify in Java**, but there will be a Certificate Expired error in case of signing data in Java and **verify in Java**. In both of cases, I used the same verify method, the same private key and public certificate.

Please tell me why? And what should I do if I want to bypass the Certificate Expired validating when verifying the digital signature?

Thanks,

Sign method in C#.NET

```
private static string SignData(byte[] data, string pkcs12FileUrl, string pkcs12Password)
    {
        X509Certificate2 signerCert = new X509Certificate2(pkcs12FileUrl, pkcs12Password);
        ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(data);
        SignedCms signed = new SignedCms(content, true);
        CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(signerCert);
        signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.None;
        signed.ComputeSignature(signer);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(signed.Encode());
    }
```

Sign method in Java

```
public static String SignData(byte[] data, String pkcs12File, String pkcs12Password)
    throws Exception
{
        if(Security.getProvider("BC")==null)
        {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        }
        KeyStore keyStore = getPkcs12Info(pkcs12File, pkcs12Password);

        Enumeration<String> aliasesList = keyStore.aliases();
        String aliasName = "";
        while (aliasesList.hasMoreElements())
        {
            aliasName = aliasesList.nextElement().toString();
        }

        X509Certificate signerCert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(aliasName);
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(aliasName,pkcs12Password.toCharArray());

        CMSSignedDataGenerator Signer = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        Signer.addSigner(privateKey, signerCert, CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA1);

        CMSProcessableByteArray digestContent = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data);

        CMSSignedData Signed = Signer.generate(digestContent, false, "BC");
        return Base64.encode(Signed.getEncoded());

}

private static  KeyStore getPkcs12Info(String pkcs12File, String pkcs12Password) throws Exception
{
    //KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(pkcs12File), pkcs12Password.toCharArray());
        return keyStore;
}
```

Verify method in Java

```
public static boolean VerifySignature(byte[] data, String digitalSignature, InputStream publicCertFile) throws Exception
{
    if(Security.getProvider("BC")==null)
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }
    CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509","BC");
    X509Certificate publicCert = (X509Certificate)factory.generateCertificate(publicCertFile);
    CMSProcessableByteArray digestContent = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data);
    CMSSignedData Signed = new CMSSignedData(digestContent,Base64.decode(digitalSignature));
    SignerInformation Signer=(SignerInformation)Signed.getSignerInfos().getSigners().iterator().next();
    return Signer.verify(publicCert, "BC");
}
```

Comment: Could you supply (links to) sample signatures having that issue and the public certificates involved?

Comment: Thank you for considering my topic. The problem had been solved as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you sign a document with a certificate that has already expired, it is already pointless. The certificate has already expired and should not be put to new uses. Verifying a document whose signing certificate has expired makes sense since at least you know the certificate was valid when the document was signed. Unless it was signed by .NET apparently. Sounds like a bug in .NET to me.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is a .NET bug or not, but I found this link http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.encryption.bouncy-castle.devel/768 that related my problem. However I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @anhtuangv If by 'fix it' you mean 'sign a document with Java and an expired certificate', you *can't* fix it, and you *don't want* to fix it. It is an insecure practice. The way to fix it is to renew the certificate.

Comment: Yes, it's better to renew the certificate as you said. However, in my case, I don't want to renew the certificate whenever it's expired. Because I just use digital signature to authenticate the request and response message between the web services. If I renew it I have to send the new certificate to my all partners and my all partners also have to send me their new certificate (if their certificate was expired). Moreover, the system will be error if I forget to do this.

Comment: @anhtuangv None of that is true. The certificate accompanies the signature. You don't have to distribute it yourself. A digital signature with an expired signature is legally meaningless. You may as well stop using them is you don't understand the requirements and implications and/or you aren't willing or able to implement them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I found this topic [Java implementation of C# SignedCms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013111/java-implementation-of-c-sharp-signedcms?rq=1) and tried to change my Sign method's code in Java. Finally, it works so well. Here my updated code in Java

```
public static String SignData(byte[] data, String pkcs12File, String pkcs12Password)
    throws Exception
{
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DEROutputStream derOut = new DEROutputStream(byteArrOut);
        try
        {
            if(Security.getProvider("BC")==null)
            {
                Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            }
            KeyStore keyStore = getPkcs12Info(pkcs12File, pkcs12Password);

            Enumeration<String> aliasesList = keyStore.aliases();
            String aliasName = "";
            while (aliasesList.hasMoreElements())
            {
                aliasName = aliasesList.nextElement().toString();
            }

            X509Certificate signerCert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(aliasName);
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(aliasName, pkcs12Password.toCharArray());

            List certList = new ArrayList();
            Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);

            JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder builder = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder().setProvider("BC").setDirectSignature(true);


            CMSSignedDataGenerator signer = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
            signer.addSignerInfoGenerator(builder.build("SHA1withRSA", privateKey, signerCert));
            signer.addCertificates(certs);

            CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data);
            CMSSignedData signed = signer.generate(msg, false);

            derOut.writeObject(signed.toASN1Structure().toASN1Primitive());
            return Base64.encode(byteArrOut.toByteArray());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            derOut.close();
            byteArrOut.close();
        }

}
```